# Please find the error in below written code for asp + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function abc()
{
   return confirm('Are u sure');
}
</script>


<asp: Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onClick="btnSubmit_Click" onClientClick="abc" Text="Submit/>
```

When I click the button the message box appears if I hit the cancel Button still the function for `onClick` is called instead it should not.
But if I write JavaScript code directly in the tag it works properly.

Comment: You probably need to add `()` after `abc`

Comment: i can't see how this is working fully. does btnSubmit_Click call abc() ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onClientClick="return abc()"
```

the `return` is the essential bit.

Comment: +1: but you should elaborate in also stating that the function should have a specific return. If he doesn't alter his function, it will always return false and never allow the postback even during valid "ok" events.

Comment: +1 jamie. your answer addresses the question more directly than mine.. tho of course, i do query an explicit return value :-)

Comment: @joel Etherton - from what I see/saw his abc method returns the result of `confirm` - which itself returns a boolean.

Comment: true dat. I didn't see it returning that earlier, just the confirm. Probably I overlooked it.